# In a JPA sql query, HIbernate can't resolve the foreignKey column

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have a springboot project ( `v2.0.2.RELEASE` ).
I have two entities `Aliment` and `Freezer`.
`Aliment.freezer_id` is a foreign key towards `Freezer.Id`.

In my aliment `CrudRepository` I use `@Query` on methods to write JPA sql:

```
@Query("select distinct al from Aliment al WHERE al.freezer_id = :freezerId")
Set<Aliment> findFreezerContent(@Param("freezerId")Long freezerId);
```

I get the following error which seems pretty clear

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property: freezer_id of: *my query*

I explicitely set the column name to be `freezer_id` throught annotation
`@JoinColumn(name="freezer_id", referencedColumnName="id")`

I use postgresql and I see in pg_admin that the column is created by hibernate.

#### Part of the code is provided below:

**Aliment.java**

```
@Entity
public class Aliment extends EntityRoot {
    
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name="freezer_ida", referencedColumnName="id")
    private Freezer freezer;



    @Column(name="name")
    private String name;

    @Column(name="category")
    private String category;

    @Column(name="iconic_font_name")
    private String iconicFontName;

    @Column(name="quantity")
    private Double quantity;

    @Column(name="quantity_unit")
    private String quantityUnit;

    @Column(name="stored_date")
    private Date storedDate;

    @Column(name="expiration_date")
    private Date expirationDate;
 
    //other methods
}
```

**Freezer.java**

```
@Entity
public class Freezer extends EntityRoot {


    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "freezer", cascade= CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Set<Aliment> content;



    @Column(name="name")
    private String name;

    //other methods
}
```

**AlimentRepository.java**

```
public interface AlimentRepository extends CrudRepository<Aliment, Long> {

    @Query("select distinct al from Aliment al WHERE al.freezer_id = :freezerId")
    Set<Aliment> findFreezerContent(@Param("freezerId")Long freezerId);
}
```

EntityRoot.java

```
@MappedSuperclass  
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS) 
public abstract class EntityRoot {
    @Id @GeneratedValue @Column(name="id")
    protected Long id;
    
    @Generated(value = GenerationTime.INSERT)
    @Temporal(value=TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @Column(name="creation_timestamp", insertable=false)
    protected Date creationTimestamp;

    @Generated(value = GenerationTime.ALWAYS)
    @Temporal(value=TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @Column(name="update_timestamp")
    protected Date updateTimestamp;

    //other methods
}
```

My goals was to not use a `join`.
Is it possible?

Comment: add all the properties, it would be better

Comment: I added the all the properties and the super class too ; )

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is an issue in your HQL query.

you cannot map SQL column name `freezer_id` in your HQL query.

You need to write the HQL query by the attribute name.

Please change query to this :

`@Query("select distinct al from Aliment al WHERE al.freezer.id = :freezerId")`

Comment: See this also, you can use native queries if you specify it : https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-jpa-query

Comment: We can specify native SQL query. But you cannot mix up SQL syntax or column name in your HQL query.